# using a matrix table for mathematical purpose

Tags: support, mathjax

I need to know how to use matrices on this site for a mathematical argument, maybe this question was asked a lot, but I couldn't find the answer for this through the site, any link?

Comment: Please read this: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/5023

Comment: Also related: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/12777/how-to-input-matrices-when-posting-questions-at-math-stackexchange and http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/11846/matrix-and-other-arrays-converter-to-latex-mathjax